Is there a way that Mosyle MDM blocks certain IPs / ports (using proxy)?
I tried to use a proxy that I’m hosting on my computer and have set up all of my devices’ proxies to my computer IP address and the port (3000). Like any other proxy, it works by listening and intercepting packets sent from my devices (configured), sending the request to google on my computer, and sending the response from my computer to my devices. When I’m at school, it didn’t work and it just kept loading and loading until it says, “Website.com took too long to respond!”
Edit: Here's the code that I currently have:
let net = require(`net`);
let server = net.createServer();

server.on(`connection`, (clientSocket) => {
    clientSocket.on(`data`, (chunk) => {
    let request = chunk.toString().split(`\n`)[0];
    let [method, target] = request.split(` `);
        if (method == `CONNECT` && target) {
        let [hostname, port] = target.split(`:`);
        let clientIP = clientSocket.remoteAddress;
            console.log(`Received CONNECT request: ${target} from IP: ${clientIP}`);
                let targetSocket = net.connect(port, hostname, () => {
                    console.log(`Connected to target: ${hostname}`);
                    clientSocket.write(`HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established\r\n\r\n`);
                    targetSocket.pipe(clientSocket);
                    clientSocket.pipe(targetSocket);
                });
                targetSocket.on(`error`, (error) => {
                    console.log(`Error connecting to target: ${hostname}`, error.message);
                    clientSocket.end();
                });
            } else console.log(`Invalid request or non-CONNECT method received from ${clientSocket.remoteAddress}`);
        });
    clientSocket.on(`error`, (error) => console.log(`Client socket error: ${error.message}`));
});

server.listen(3000, () => console.log(`Proxy server listening on port 3000`));

In reality, the proxy worked at home, and I could prove that the packets were indeed being intercepted and sent from my computer. However, when I’m at school and I properly configured the IP and port, it didn’t work, it’s the issue above, where it’s just blank and says that it took too long to respond. I think that this is because Mosyle MDM blocks certain IPs and ports, which would prevent what I’m doing from working. However, there are numerous other proxies (Rammerhead) that I use and also works. I’ll edit this post and send the code that I’m using when I get home. I just wanted to get my problem across first, thanks if you’ve read this far!
